# Xpath regex and preg-match function

Tags: php, regex, xpath, preg-match

I have this code:

```
<div class="small_map_wrapper">
                <script type="text/javascript">loadMap('44.7958873,20.471077899999954');</script>
```

I will fetch this content with:

```
$string = $xpath->query("//div[@class='small_map_wrapper']/@script")->item(0)->textContent;
```

then i try to get this numbers '44.7958873,20.471077899999954' with preg_match:

```
preg_match('/.*loadMap([\d.,]+)<.*/', $string, $matches); 
list($lat, $lng) = explode(',', $matches[1]);
$data['lat'] = $lat; 
$data['lng'] = $lng;
```

BUT SOMETHING IN CODE I WROTE WRONG. I cant see error. Someone see error because after start this code $data['lat'] is 0, lng too
(my english is not very well, sorry for that)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please fix the wording of your question and take a look into the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to write a good question. For example it would be good to know if you have a problem with the regex or with the xpath. It sounds that you're asking two questions in one, please be more specifc, don't just throw problems in.

Comment: sorry, my problem was been regex.

Comment: What is your specific problem with the regex? What are you missing to change it according to your needs? Can you write a bit more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a complicated regular expression, you can use a much easier to use function called [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf):

```
$r = sscanf($str, "loadMap('%f,%f", $lat, $lng);
```

It allows you to directly parse those two float values into variables for the string given ([Demo](http://codepad.org/osD8jrFf)).

Answer (score 0):

`@script` - this is wrong. You are trying to get an attribute called `script`, not the tag. Remove that `@`.

Your regex is also wrong, because it's looking for something like `loadMap12.345,67.890<`. Try this regex instead: `/loadMap\('([0-9.,]+)'\)/`

That should do it.

Comment: sorry but:   preg_match("/loadMap\('([0-9.,]+)'\)/", $string, $matches);  
also give 0,0 result :(

Comment: You didn't put backslashes before the `()` like I did. Please pay closer attention ;)